# htaccess for new image folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to rewrite the url to another url.

because i already made a subdomain for my images and i want all the url requesting for my images should get in the new image domain.

for example.

old image link - http://www.website.com/uploaded/art/sd.jpg
should get to - http://img.website.com/uploaded/art/sd.jpg

another one

old image link - http://www.website.com/uploaded/photo/ss.jpg
should get to - http://img.website.com/uploaded/photo/ss.jpg

i have my subfolders in my uploaded folder.
here is my htaccess for now and it seems i cant get it to work.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^uploaded/(.*)$ http://img.website.com/uploaded/$1 [R=301,L]

# Use PHP5.4 as default
#AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L,NC]

</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 day"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 18000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/plain "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 18000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
```

this htaccess is saved to my public html folder. main root of my website.

Comment: What happens when you go to **oldsite/uploaded/foobar** ?

Comment: @starkeen that will be the url of my image. the storage location


ex. if location is www.website.com/uploaded/foobar/img.jpg


it should get literally to img.website.com/uploaded/foobar/img.jpg


is this possible?

Comment: Yes. you already have a rule for this. what exactly is not working?

Comment: @starkeen its not working. its not getting to the new url.

Comment: Is your htaccess located in /uploads ?

Comment: no.. at the root of my website.. in public_html folder

Comment: @starkeen if im browsing the uploaded folder im still seeing the directory of the true folder not the the directory of img.website.com/uploaded

Comment: I think the problem is that you have another htaccess in uploaded folder and that is conflicting with the request.

Comment: @starkeen no i dont have any htaccess to my uploaded folder

Comment: I added an answer. I think rewrite module isnt enabled on your server. You can use mod-alias based solution. see my answer bellow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an htaccess in the **/uploaded** folder and add the following redirect :

```
Redirect 302 /uploaded/ http://img.website.com/uploaded/
```

This will redirect all requests from **/uploaded** folder to the new destination, eg : **example.com/uploaded/foobar** to  **http://img.website.com/uploaded/foobar** .

You change the redirect status to 301 (permanent redirect) when you are sure it's working ok.

Comment: hi thank you for this other solution it works fine now. how i wish is that the url shouldn`t change but this works the way i want it too.

Comment: i have one question, does this fulfill also the uploading? if i upload to my old folder? will it upload to the new folder instead?